# How can I exclude current post from related posts in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

My code is:

```
<div class="recent-posts">

  {% for post in site.posts |  limit:3 %}

  <div class="recent-posts-inline">

      {% if post.featured-image %}{% include post-featured-image.html image=post.featured-image alt=page.featured-image-alt %}{% endif %}

    <h4>
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </h4>

    <p>{{ post.excerpt | strip_html | strip_newlines | truncate: 156 }}</p>
    <p><a href="{{ post.url }}">Read More...</a></p>
  </div>

  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I have tried using where_exp filter but to no avail. That's why I have to ask this question again.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [page variable](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#page-variables) in an if-check. Only do something if the post is not the same title as the current page. If you want a different comparison, you can check the `.url`, `.id`, or `.name`.

```
<div class="recent-posts">

  {% for post in site.posts |  limit:3 %}
    {% if post.title != page.title %}

      <div class="recent-posts-inline">
      ...

    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem. However, I have 5 posts in my _posts folder, but only two posts are displaying. It is not taking 3rd post.

Comment: Done. The only changed I did was to increase the limit to 4.